# Why My Laravel 6 CMS not generating Sitemap of URL

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I have laravel 6 CMS but its not generating sitemap for my site .So please help me to give required files for that .this cms have two directoris 1 root folder and second is out from root folder.

[image]

[image]

So if there is any expert in laravel 6 Please provide me sitemap generator files..with a little bit instrustions.Sitemap should include all urls of my site with 1.0 periority . and basic pages should be with low periority e.g contact us,about us,privacy policy etc.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Laravel (at least up to the current version) doesn't include site-map generation capability. Nevertheless, there are packages available for Laravel which can be installed and used to automatically generate site maps. One of these packages is the [Laravel Sitemap](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-sitemap) packages by Spaite. [This article](https://freek.dev/557-automatically-generate-a-sitemap-in-laravel) walks through in detail but you can read the docs on the GitHub page for more configuration options.